# Slice string in python

Tags: python, string, slice

I just want to slice string from the beginning.As like I have a sentences:

```
"All the best wishes"
```

I want to get

```
"the best wishes" , "best wishes", "wishes".
```

Any solution please,Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> words
['All', 'the', 'best', 'wishes']
>>> [" ".join(words[i:]) for i in range(len(words))]
['All the best wishes', 'the best wishes', 'best wishes', 'wishes']
>>> [" ".join(words[i:]) for i in range(len(words))][1:]
['the best wishes', 'best wishes', 'wishes']
```

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
searchWords.extend([' '.join(words[i:]) for i in xrange(1, len(words))])
```

Comment: in the original code start xrange(or range) from 1. please try to understand how it works, it's not rocket science ;)

Comment: You mean `searchWords.extend([' '.join(words[:i]) for i in xrange(-1, len(words))])`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "All the best wishes"
[a.split(None,x)[-1] for x in xrange(1, len (a.split()))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Eh, pythoners;]

You can always do it with simple loop and function:

```
def parts(s, fromstart=True):
    sl, slp, idx = s.split(), [], 0 if fromstart else -1
    while len(sl)>1:
        sl.pop(idx)
        slp.append(' '.join(sl))
    return slp

s = 'All the best wishes'
parts(s) # -> ['the best wishes', 'best wishes', 'wishes']
parts(s,False) # -> ['All the best', 'All the', 'All']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "All the best wishes"
[' '.join(s.split()[x:]) for x in xrange(1, len(s.split()))]
```